# Google violates same origin policy using KML with Google Maps?

Tags: kml, google-maps-api

Does Google Violate the same origin policy when it tries to access the KML files from a globally accessible server?

The condition for Google maps to display the KML is that it should be globally accessible. Now there are 2 problems with this:

1. Security of the KML files. (This can be avoided by using geoXML3)
2. Violating the Same-Origin Policy.

Is there a way around to the same-origin policy?

How does google parse the KML file?

Comment: A marginally related point from the W3C: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#Who.27s_not_willing_to_get_on_board.3F

Answer (score 5):

From the Google Maps premier [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#intranet_kml):

> The KmlLayer class that generates KML overlays in the Google Maps API
>   uses a Google hosted service to retrieve and parse KML files for
>   rendering. Consequently it is not possible to display KML files that
>   are not hosted at a URL that is available publicly accessible, or that
>   require authentication to access.
>
> If you need to develop applications that use KML files hosted on
>   intranet sites we recommend that you either:
>
> Use the Google Earth API which supports client side parsing and
>   rendering of KML.
>
> Render the KML on the client side by using
>   third-party JavaScript libraries. As the KML file is analyzed by the
>   browser, performance may be lower than by using the KmlLayer class.

This doesn't breach the same-origin policy as the files are sent to the browser from a Google server rather than the original source server of the KML URL.

You could consider making URLs that are very difficult to guess such as using a different [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) for each request.  But you would still need to trust Google to securely handle your kml and keep it secret.

Comment: I am still confused - Does google download the KML file on its local server and parse it and display it on Google map ?

Comment: @Vinit.  yes that is correct.

Comment: The GeoXML3 documentation says - 
"Geoxml3 is subject to the same cross-domain download restrictions as any JavaScript, so any KML document you expect it to process will need to be served from the same domain as the containing map page.
Then my question is how does Google get around this?

Comment: It does not break the same-origin policy as the files are going through Google's servers.  The origin refers to the actual URL that the browser is requesting.

Comment: Google must be having a javascript similar to geoxml i suppose which parses the KML that we provide,right?
But when google is trying to access the KML from the url that we provide, isnt it trying to access something which is not in its domain, from the javascript?

Comment: The Google server acts as a proxy.  So example.com/test.kml could become google.com/example-com/test.html.   Geoxml would only see a file from google, and not your server.  Of course they may not actually be using Geoxml internally.  If you are interested about the internals of Google Maps try running it with Firebug, or Chrome developer tools.  This will show you exactly what URLs are being accessed.